# Firefox closes suddenly

Tags: firefox, crash, runtime-error

I am experiencing a rather strange issue with my Firefox browser. It just closes without any notice, and even the crash prompt or window doesn't show up even though I have set it so that it should show up.
It leaves me no place or chance to analyze it

Can someone please help me diagnose this issue of sudden closure of Firefox

Comment: Did you try to follow the [official troubleshoot page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-crashes-troubleshoot-prevent-and-get-help) of Firefox?

Comment: @CaldeiraG Thank you, but I don't suppose they would provide information regarding sudden automated random closing of firefox, or do they?

Answer (score 0):

Is it crashing or just hanging? Could be Malware, run a deep scan first ofc
Check to see if the crash happens in Safe Mode (see below).
Try a clean reinstall (see Firefox keeps crashing at startup).
Otherwise, follow these steps in order.

Table of Contents
Update your software
Update Firefox
Update and troubleshoot your Flash plugin
Update Windows
Update your drivers
Update your Internet Security software
Check for viruses or spyware
Check to see if the crash happens in Safe Mode
The crash still happens in Safe Mode
The crash doesn't happen in Safe Mode
Check your hardware
Check your RAM for errors
Get help fixing this crash
Ask for help in the Community Support forum

Comment: Tnx Tony for taking the time,Yes it is just crashing,& it is not even a normal crash, no prompt,no crash reports,nothing,it just closes.I have tried safe mode firefox, but it is still crashing or sometimes not even opening up.I have also tried a clean install,and also tried running it as a totally newly created user but it is still crashing.I don't have Flash Plugin installed and I have disabled it,due to security reasons,in all of my browsers.Windows is fully updated.SFC /SCANNOW and Dism commands have been issued and no problems were found.I really don't know how to diagnose this